# Problem with `sc_consensus_grandpa::grandpa_peers_set_config' in service.rs

Tags: substrate-node, service

I cloned the substrate-node-template and upgraded the dependencies to:

```
git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk", branch = "master"
```

for reference, the original branch was `"polkadot-v1.0.0"`.
I have another node which was also referencing  `"polkadot-v1.0.0"`, and updated it the same way to the `master` branch of polkadot-sdk.
my problem happens in `service.rs`:
in substrate-node-template/service.rs, the type returned by

`sc_consensus_grandpa::grandpa_peers_set_config(grandpa_protocol_name.clone())`

is as expected

`(NonDefaultSetConfig, Box<dyn NotificationService>)`

But, in my other node, the same functions only returns the type:

`NonDefaultSetConfig`

and this creates a bunch of errors in `service.rs`.
Both cargo.toml in the Node folder are identical, how is this possible? how can this be fixed?
Let me know if  additionnal information are needed.
Thanks in advance,
Kazu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this function was modified with this [PR](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/1370) and it indeed has a new return type now. You might have switched to `master` branch in your other node before this PR was merged, so dependencies are locked with the commit that is earlier than this [one](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/commit/e71c484d5bd12330e16f568ad582e1fc1c878669). If you do `cargo update` in the other node, it will sync with the latest commit and it also shouldn't compile.

To fix this, you can point your dependencies to a release branch (e.g `polkadot-v1.5.0`), instead of `master` and avoid this kind of situations in the future. Or update the dependencies of `substrate-node-template` to specific commit that is older than this PR or the one your other node is pointing at (check in `Cargo.lock` for `sc-network` after `master#`):

```sh
# this will update all `polkadot-sdk` dependencies
cargo update -p sc-network --precise <commit hash>
```